# Converting HTML File into Text File

Tags: jsoup

I am given a html file, and I need to move the text it into a new textFile which I will create. I do not know if I am on the right track. Am I supposed to first turn it into a Document and then a textFile? Is what I am currently doing correct? Sorry, I am a beginner at this and am kind of confused.

```
public void parseIntoFile(){
    Document docParse = Jsoup.parse("example.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML is typically used to describe a document so it already is a document. Your job would be to gather the described portions of that document and put together your text file in a manner you choose to fit. Such as, a `<h1>` is the heading for a page. `<p>` contains a paragraph of text and so on.

This is, in part, the reason for the doctype (DTD) at the top. It's the Document Type Definition that describes the "type" or meaning of each element within the document.